# setText() displaying address instead of a value in Android

Tags: android, settext

I have just started to program in Android and I am still learning. I wanted to check if a year changes automatically when a nextMonth() method is used in case of December and January or whether I should change it with a few if statements. However, I canot display the value of that, instead I get an address. Here is my code:

```
TextView checkMonValue;

MonthDisplayHelper currentMonth = new MonthDisplayHelper(2012, 11);
MonthDisplayHelper nextMon = currentMonth;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    checkMonValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.monthValue);

    checkMonValue.setText(String.valueOf(changeOfYear()));

}

public String changeOfYear(){

    nextMon.nextMonth();
    return nextMon + "" + nextMon.getYear();
}
```

And that is what get's displayed: Android.util.MonthDisplayHelper@44ee34e02013

Comment: You're trying to print an object. It will go to the object's toString method and return something quite unreadable like that. Search for the appropriate methods in MonthDisplayHelper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are appending `nextMon` itself in your return value of `changeOfYear()` method. This way its returning the qualified name and address of `nextMon` as `Android.util.MonthDisplayHelper@44ee34e0` appended with year as `2013`.

Please correct to append `nextMon.getMonth()` and `nextMon.getYear()`

```
 public String changeOfYear(){
   nextMon.nextMonth();
   return nextMon.getMonth() + "" + nextMon.getYear();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`nextMon` is an object as your return indicates. When you call `nextMonth()` you're issuing the command to increment the month but not actually retrieving anything.

Instead do this:

```
public String changeOfYear(){
    nextMon.nextMonth();
    return nextMon.getMonth() + " " + nextMon.getYear();
}
```

Note that I put a space in there where you only had `""`. You can even see this on your return:  Android.util.MonthDisplayHelper@44ee34e0`2013`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `nextMon` is some type you defined, `MonthDisplayHelper`, and you haven't overridden the `toString()` method.

You can implement that method to return something meaningful, or, perhaps you meant to concatenate something different in this line:

```
return nextMon + "" + nextMon.getYear();
```

Probably something like this is what you want, `nextMon.getMonth()` or some method on `nextMon`.